# Recreate Lubuntu LXDE visual style in Debian

Tags: debian, ubuntu, lxde, theme, lubuntu

My Debian's LXDE looks quite different Lubuntu; and I want it to look more similar. I've found this:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Artwork/Incoming/Oneiric/Ozone

detailing the changes from the default visual elements, although it's for a much older version of Ubuntu, and it doesn't explain how to apply all this.

How do I do it?

Note: I'm using Debian Stretch but I guess the question is more general.

Comment: You are looking to theme your desktop.

Comment: That too. But an LXDE theme doesn't change graphical elements of apps running under LXDE.